# Mocking Module Dependencies in Karma/Jasmine for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to compose some unit tests in Karma/Jasmine for a particular module in my project, `destination-filters`.

Module Decleration:

```
angular.module('destination-filter', ['ngSanitize']);
```

My tests fail unless I remove `ngSanitize` as a dependency. To my understanding that is because when the module is instantiated it will try and pull in that dependency but because in my spec.js file I haven't declared that module it is failing.

Spec File:

```
describe('Destination Filter Controller', function () {

  // Set the variables
  var $controller;
  var mockNgSanitize;

  beforeEach(module('destination-filter'));

  beforeEach(function() {
      module(function($provide) {
          $provide.value('ngSanitize', mockNgSanitize);
      });
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
      $controller = _$controller_('DestinationFilterController');
  }));

  it('should expect the controller to not be null', function() {
      // Check the controller is set
      expect($controller).not.toBeNull();
  });

});
```

Previously, when mocking out services or functions, the `$provide` method has proven very useful but I'm not sure my use of it is correct here. I'm assuming `$provide` used in this way can't mock entire modules but rather services?

To clarify, if I remove the `...['ngSantize'])...` from my module deceleration the tests instantiate correctly. The error I am receiving with it left in is `Error: [$injector:modulerr] destination-filter`

Comment: does your karma configuration load the `angular-sanitize.js` file?

Comment: It doesn't. I'm a little afraid to start adding in seperate files in there. I know that is what it is used for but I really don't want to have to start putting lots of files in there. Unless you think its fair enough to do so perhaps. Is it standard practice?

Comment: You need to include the JS files you use in your code, so the tests will run. It's just an angular dependency. I don't see why not to include it for the tests.

Comment: Yeah that has done the trick cheers.

Comment: @yarons, you saved my day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three options you could take for using ngSanitize in your tests:

1. inject the service into your test
2. stub a method call on ngSanitize
3. mock the entire ngSanitize service

The option you choose is really dependent on the use of ngSanitize in your working code (not your test code).

Whichever one you go for you need to make the service available in your test, there is no need for `$provider` (this covers option 1 and there is no need to do any more than this if you just want to make this available to your filter):

```
beforeEach(module('ngSanitize'));    

beforeEach(inject(function(_ngSanitize_) { // the underscores are needed
    mockNgSanitize = _ngSanitize_;
}));
```

Also, make sure that all js files are picked up and loaded by karma. You can define this in `karma.conf.js` by adding them to the `files:` property.

#### 2. Stub a method on the service

I like stubs and find them very useful when writing tests. Your tests should only test one thing, in your case a filter. Stubs give you more control over your tests and allow you to isolate the thing under test.

Typically filters, controllers, anything call on lots of other things (services or factories like $http or ngSanitize).

Assuming that your filter is using ngSanitize's `$sanitize` to sanitize some html you could stub out that method to return sanitized html you have defined to test against your expectations:

```
// in a beforeEach

spyOn(mockNgSanitize, "$sanitize").and.returnValue('<some>sanitized<html>');

mockNgSanitized.$sanitize(yourDirtyHtml);
```

[See the jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>and.returnValue</code>) for more info.

You might have to play around with spying on the right service but this should work ok.

#### 3. Mock the entire service

I don't think you want to go with this option because it will drive you insane figuring out what needs mocking plus mocks can create unrealistic expectations and also, not particularly useful for your use case. If you really want to have a go then something like the below is heading in the right direction (again [see the jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>createSpyObj</code>))

```
beforeEach(function() {
    mockNgSanitize = ('ngSanitize', ['linky', '$sanitize', '$sanitizeProvider'];
});

it('mocks the ngSanitize service', function() {
    expect(mockNgSanitize.linky).toBeDefined(); 
});
```

NB: in all the code above make sure you continue to declare any variables up at the top of your describe block.

Comment: Thanks for the fully fledged answer. Method one worked straight away but these other methods will be very helpful for other parts of my tests so thanks a lot!